# Switching from TightVNC to other applications on the client machine

Tags: windows-10, tightvnc

I'm looking for a way to switch away from TightVNC without leaving full-screen mode. With my current configuration - in TightVNC 2.8.63, which seems to be the latest version - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is always sent to the host machine, and I haven't found a keyboard shortcut to override that.

For comparison, when Windows Remote Desktop is in full-screen mode with its "connection bar" hidden, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> displays the connection bar, and while it is displayed, keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, Windows key, etc are sent to the client machine instead of the host.

A method of sending <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the client machine would be my preferred solution. But there are certainly other potential solutions which would be usable, such as minimizing the TightVNC window, or displaying the client machine's taskbar on top of the TightVNC window. The issue I am trying to avoid is the necessity of exiting full-screen to return to the client machine.